# How to refresh a parent page after closing sharepoint dialog?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dialog, modal-dialog

How to refresh a parent page after closing sharepoint dialog?
Here is my coding to open a pop-up.

```
<input type="button" value="Add" class="button submit" style="width: 80px" onclick="javascript:OpenAttachmentUpload()" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    //User Defined Function to Open Dialog Framework
    function OpenAttachmentUpload() {

        var strPageURL = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Dialogs/AttachUpload.aspx") %>';
        //OpenFixCustomDialog(strPageURL, "Attachment");
        OpenCustomDialog(strPageURL, 350, 200, "Attachment");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

here is the script.

```
function OpenCustomDialog(dialogUrl, dialogWidth, dialogHeight, dialogTitle, dialogAllowMaximize, dialogShowClose) {

    var options = {
        url: dialogUrl,
        allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,
        showClose: dialogShowClose,
        width: dialogWidth,
        height: dialogHeight,
        title: dialogTitle,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback3)
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

After opening it, when I close the pop-up **(~/Dialogs/AttachUpload.aspx)** , I wanna refresh the parent page.
How can I do it?
I google and see **SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage** but still can't find an answer for me.
Thanks.

P.s
I don't know much about SharePoint.

Comment: Where you try call SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage? You should call it from your dialogReturnValueCallback

Comment: @MishaU-> sry for late reply.
OpenCustomDialog function is in a js file.
I call it from the parent page.
What do you mean **You should call it from your dialogReturnValueCallback**. I don't get it since I am not familiar with SharePoint.

Comment: You should call it from your dialogReturnValueCallback - call SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage in callback method that you set for option property dialogReturnValueCallback :). You have answer below what i mean

Comment: That will work when open a DispForm.aspx and execute an exclusion?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're almost there.

In the option `dialogReturnValueCallback` you can define a function that will be executed after the dialog was closed. By now you create a delegate pointing to `CloseCallback3` but this is not defined in your code.

If you call `SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage` in this callback method the page gets refreshed after the dialog was closed with *OK*.

```
 var options = 
 {
        url: dialogUrl,
        allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,
        showClose: dialogShowClose,
        width: dialogWidth,
        height: dialogHeight,
        title: dialogTitle,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult) 
        { 
          SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult) 
        }
 }
```

**Btw:**
You use `javascript:` in the `onclick` of the button. This is not necessary. this is only required in the `href` of an `a` tag

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes it is OK now. You saved my life ? I was trying to figure out this problem the whole day yesterday.
Thanks a lot again !!!

Answer (score 26):

You can also use the build-in function "**RefreshOnDialogClose**"

```
 SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    url: dialogUrl,         
    allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,         
    showClose: dialogShowClose,         
    width: dialogWidth,         
    height: dialogHeight,         
    title: dialogTitle,         
    dialogReturnValueCallback: RefreshOnDialogClose  
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code on click of a button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshParent() 
    {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Ok, null);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to refresh the page if changes were made you can use the following call back instead.

```
var options = 
{
    url: dialogUrl,
    allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,
    showClose: dialogShowClose,
    width: dialogWidth,
    height: dialogHeight,
    title: dialogTitle,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult) 
    {
        if (dialogResult != SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel)
        {
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult)
        }
    }
}
```

Saves you from refreshing the page if the user hit cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Try java-script code as below in Closecall back.

window.location = window.location;